# Swift: Do For-In Loop Parameters Optimize Away Needless Accesses?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, for-loop

### Context:

Suppose I want to enumerate the `NSTableColumn` objects of an `NSTableView` and I do this:

```
for column: NSTableColumn in someTableView.tableColumns
{
    [...]
}
```

In Objective-C, it was a very well-known performance optimization to avoid unnecessary selector calls in loop parameters, so we'd factor that out like this:

```
NSArray *columns = [someTableView tableColumns];
for (NSTableColumn *column in columns)
{
   [...]
}
```

### Question:

Is this still needed in Swift, or will the compiler now factor out the repetitive access during optimization? Since `Array` is now a value type, if each loop iteration involved re-creating it, that would seem expensive.

(Apologies if it's been asked before; it's a really hard thing to Google.)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by factor out and optimize. The for loop loops over a copy which is made once before the loop starts. There are no "accesses".  Is that what you needed to know?

Comment: Or is the question more what a for loop is? It is actually a while loop that calls a sequence iterator's `next()` each time.